# How to extract the zip code from a line of address?

Tags: java, regex

I've been working on this for a while, but got no solution. The problem is I have multiple lines of addresses like the following:

```
Enright Ave 98213         62330   Saint Louis       Missouri        314-544-0921
```

I've considered to break the line by empty space to match the five consecutive number as the zip code (62330), but this does not work since sometimes the address has such label (98213) in it, can anybody provide some suggestions on it? thanks

Comment: does the zipcode appear at a particular position? E.g. usually it's directly after the state code/state name.

Comment: Every line of address is like the one above, the zip code is appeared before the city and after the street address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ack yourfile.txt -o --match '[0-9]{5}(?!.*([0-9]{5}))'
```

What this does is find the last 5 digit number on each line

Comment: can you please explain the regex you provided, I am newbie to it. thanks

Comment: `[0-9]{5}` matches a five number sequence. `foo(?!.*foo)` is a negative lookahead, which matches the last element.  See http://frightanic.wordpress.com/2007/06/08/regex-match-last-occurrence/ for more details.  So combining the two, you get [0-9]{5}(?!.*([0-9]{5}))

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:  `([0-9]*[-]*[0-9]*)*` when testing your line [here](http://regexpal.com/)